# status 403 unauthorized en proyecto spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea

quería hacerles una consulta estoy empezando a practicar spring boot pero tengo la siguiente duda estoy creando un proyecto de microservicios de Udemy.

pasa que cuando desde el pasman pruebo uno de mis controladores, me devuelve un 403 unauthorized, **leyendo dice que el servidor si recibió mi solicitud, pero se deniega a devolverme una respuesta**, el problema es que no he programado nada que tenga roles en este momento. sinceramente nose donde podría estar el error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aqui esta mi controlador

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/authentication")
public class AuthenticationController {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationService authenticationService;

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @PostMapping("sing-up")
    public ResponseEntity<?> singUp(@RequestBody User user){

        if(userService.findByUsername(user.getUsername()).isPresent()){

            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
        }

        return  new ResponseEntity<>(userService.saveUser(user), HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

    @PostMapping("sign-in")
    public ResponseEntity<?> sigIn(@RequestBody User user){

        return new ResponseEntity<>(authenticationService.sigInAndReturnJWT(user), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}
```

Osea yo tengo la base de datos en un container en dockers, lo que llegue a notar es que el container se ejecuta bien, normal esta ejecutado, pero si intento entrar al bash para ver usuarios creados, la consola se pega, y no me deja avanzar, eso fue algo raro que note y nose si tenga algo que ver.

Lo raro es que ya verifiqué mi servidor y realmente el Mysql si tiene creado correctamente el usuario admin con acceso desde cualquier lado.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

por parte del servidor parece que si esta bien.

Este es mi archivo de aplication.properties

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como verán la unica configuración que tengo es la del database con el usuario y la contraseñas correctas porque ya las probe.

Comment: Tiene pinta de que securizaste todos tus endpoint para que solo un usuario autenticado tenga acceso a ellos y se te olvidó excluir los de registro/login. Normalmente cuando se implementa la seguridad de los endpoint, el login y el registro se deben especificar como disponibles siempre. Habría que ver el archivo de configuración de seguridad para saberlo exactamente, pero tiene pinta de ser eso.

Comment: bueno acabo de modificar la pregunta y poner mi aplication.properties, como veras solo tengo configurado el spring.datasource pero esas credenciales son correctas.

Comment: No las properties, en algún sitio tienes que tener una clase de configuración de seguridad, anotada con `@EnableWebSecurity`. En ella tendrás un método similar a este: `protected void configure(HttpSecurity http){}`. Ahí tendrás algo así como `.anyRequest().authenticated()`, que securiza todos tus endpoint, además de seguramente otras cosas. Ahí es donde tienes que configurar la seguridad de tus rutas.